# Getting incorrect month difference between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have 2 dates like below :

```
Todays date = 2021-10-13 11:03:57.560

Old date = 2016-08-07 11:03:57.560
```

I want month difference from `todays date Month - Old date Month = 10 - 8 = 2`

**Code:**

```
console.log(moment().diff($scope.creationTime, 'months')); // returns 62
```

**Expected:** Current month - Old date month

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, but I am trying to get the difference of the current month-old date month. Don't want to consider the month from the old date that's why not expecting 62 as output

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow it is going to read the whole date

Comment: @BeerusDev Yes, so how do I fix that if you can share some thoughts?

Comment: Check out the fine manual here https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/571

Comment: Do you want the full month difference (what Moment does with `diff`) or just the absolute difference between the month numbers? E.g., what should the difference be between 31st of January and 1st of February - one or zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you get `62` because the two dates are 5 years and 2 months apart:

5 * 12 + 2 = 62

An easy way to drop the year difference is to use the remainder operator and do `monthDifference % 12` which will give you only the number of months, regardless of the years:

```js
function monthDiff(date1, date2) {
  const monthDifference = moment(date1).diff(moment(date2),  'months');
  return monthDifference % 12;
}


console.log(monthDiff("2021-10-13 11:03:57.560", "2016-08-07 11:03:57.560"));
console.log(monthDiff("2021-10-07 11:03:57.560", "2016-08-13 11:03:57.560"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you try this : console.log(monthDiff("2021-10-07 11:03:57.560", "2016-12-13 11:03:57.560"));. It returning 9 instead of 2. Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow yes, that's how Moment determines the difference between the two - it's from December to October, which is 10 months. But not 10 full months because it's the 13th of December to the 7th of October so the full months between the two dates are 9. This is consistent with the Moment calculation. I asked whether you want that or not as a comment under your question. My answer assumes you want to keep the Moment logic of determining dates.

Answer (score 2):

Use `month()` from **moment.js** to get the months and simple math after that:

```
const today = moment();
const someday = moment('2011-01-01 00:00Z');

console.log(today.month())
console.log(someday.month())

console.log(Math.abs(today.month()-someday.month()))
```

Comment: This will not return necessarily the same value. Try it with `moment("2021-10-07 11:03:57.560").diff(moment(" 2016-08-13 11:03:57.560"),  'months')` (the day values are flipped) returns `61` because the dates aren't *full* 62 months apart. Your code only considers month values not day values.

Comment: No @VLAZ. It returns 2. That is what is expected by the OP. There is no need to consider the day values, OP wants just the diff bw month values, right

Comment: Yes, returning `2` *is what I said is a problem*. [See here](https://jsbin.com/rihosanone/edit?js,console). Your code doesn't make a difference between *full* months. Your code will return `1` for the difference between 31st of January and 1st of February, whereas Moment will return `0` because there is not a full month between these two dates.

Comment: *I want month difference from todays date Month - Old date Month = 10 - 8 = 2*. That is what the OP says. The dates do not matter. What matters is the month in the date. As long as one date is in Feb and one in Jan it should return 1 as diff.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need moment to do that you use Date as well

```
new Date().getMonth - to get your current month
new Date('2016-08-07 11:03:57.560').getMonth() - to get the month of your old date
```

```js
console.log(new Date().getMonth() - new Date('2016-08-07 11:03:57.560').getMonth())
```

Comment: This will not return necessarily the same value. Try it with `moment("2021-10-07 11:03:57.560").diff(moment(" 2016-08-13 11:03:57.560"),  'months')` (the day values are flipped) returns `61` because the dates aren't *full* 62 months apart. Your code only considers month values not day values.

Comment: @VLAZ if you give a flipped date value in Date() it wont accept it and it will throw nan.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. See my example. The *day values* are reversed: from `10-13` and `08-07` (in the question) to `10-07` and `08-13`. Moment will take the day values into account when doing a difference and only give the *full* months difference. If there is not two *full* months difference between the two dates, `.diff()` returns `1`. Again, your code completely disregards the day values and would return `1` for the difference between the 31st of January and the 1st of February. This is inconsistent with Moment.

Comment: got you :) my code only considers the month.